# Control Flow: %rsp and return address and space provided within stack

Tags: c, x86-64

[image: Control Flow example]

It is said that the stack grows by 8 bytes and `%rsp` is decremented to make room for the return address of the next instruction call.

My question is:
Does this return address take up all 8 (bytes)? That is, are all 8 locations taken up by the return address? Or does is not take up the entire 8 bytes provided, in which case the next thing being pushed onto the stack can be pushed within these 8 bytes of space (wherever the return address left off)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes all the 8 bytes. %rsp will be decremented by exactly 8 bytes.

Comment: In this example, doesn't the return address only take up 3 bytes (since two hex digits = 1 byte)

Comment: That is true. but 5 00 bytes would be pushed

Comment: If the return address was of dynamic size, it was much harder to return from a function. It doesn't make any sense that we would have to "remember" the size. call and return are machine code instructions so they have to be very simple.

Comment: @LuisOng but how would the processor know how many bytes to pop for the return address? It has to be a fixed amount, and it has to be a size that aligns with 2, 4, 8 etc according to the processor.

Comment: So what does the stack look like if all 8 locations are taken up and there are only 3 bytes of the return address to store?

Comment: the address being pushed is 00 00 00 00 00 40 05 40